# ¿Como unificar jscript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Tengo estos dos **javascript**, los cuales debo colocar en varias paginas.

¿Como puedo unificarlos en un mismo **js**? si es que es posible tal cosa. La razón de querer unificarlo solo se debe al hecho de que ambos **js** ejecutan dentro de si la función **"copyData();"** y no me parece una buena práctica la manera en que lo he hecho.

```
<script type="text/jscript"> 

    $(".NHC").on('change'  ,function(){       

        copyData();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/jscript"> 
     $(document).on('click','input[type="image"]',function(ev)
     {
         if (!$(ev.target).is('#ib_check_horario')) {

             copyData();                   
          }             
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes solo colocalo asi:

```
<script type="text/jscript"> 

  function copyData(){
    alert('soy copyData function')
  }

  $(".NHC").on('change', function() {       
     copyData();
  });

  $(document).on('click','input[type="image"]',function(ev) {
     if (!$(ev.target).is('#ib_check_horario')) {
       copyData();                   
     }             
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Gracias... pero sigue apareciendo  "copyData();" como código duplicado. Que en principio es lo que busco evitar.

Comment: no esta duplicado, estas instanciando o llamando la función copyData en dos eventos diferentes, se duplica si copyData la declaras dos veces o la llamas para el mismo evento dos veces, si te fijas la llamas en un evento click y otro en una evento change

Comment: Me parece tienes razón. Es una respuesta aceptable. Sigo teniendo la curiosidad intelectual... por decirlo así, sobre como se haría, así que esperare otras opiniones y al final también marcare tu opinión como respuesta. En todo caso, gracias por tomarte el tiempo...

Comment: Ahí modifique mi respuesta y coloque la función copyData para que veas como quedaría, si te fijas solo existe copyData una sola vez y la llamas desde el evento click y el evento change